# data.table subset giving unexpected results

Tags: r, data.table

I am just learning R and data.table and can't figure out why this subset produce different results?

Take a look at this code:

```
x <- c("a",NA,"b","C","d")
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

z <- data.table(x,y)

z1 <- z[is.na(x), q := 2*y]


z2 <- z[, q:= 2*y]

z2a <- z2[is.na(x),]
```

`z1` has 5 observations of 3 variables. `z2a` has 1 observation 3 variables

I don't understand why `z1` is different than `z2a`. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Well you modified the original `z` when you did `z[is.na(x), q := 2*y]`, then you modified it again with `z[, q:= 2*y]`.  Have you read the data table vignettes about assignment by reference using `:=`?

Comment: also notice `z` and `z1` are the same. It's important to understand what the `:=` operator is doing and how it works.

Comment: But why does z1 have 5 observations instead of 1?

Comment: try comparing `z[is.na(x), q := 2*y][]` and `z[is.na(x), c(.SD, .(q=2*y))]` in the console. you will need to read the data.table vignettes

Comment: Because you have not filtered it to only one row. What you are doing with `[is.na(x), q := 2*y]` is saying, "for the rows where `x` is NA, update the values in column `q`"

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not filtered it to only one row. What you are doing with [is.na(x), q := 2*y] is saying, "for the rows where x is NA, update the values in column q" – SymbolixAU

This was the ticket, in combination with the note about checking the vignette (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html)

Basically, when you use := in j, i acts as a condition not as a subset.

Comment: It's normal and encouraged to answer your own question, but just copy-pasting somebody else's comment is not useful and doesn't add any new information. Please edit and make this a better answer.

Comment: I must be missing something obvious - I just wanted to flag SymbolixAU's response as the answer. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If @SymbolixAU writes their comments up as an answer, you'd mark that as the accepted answer. You'd only ever answer your question if you came up with the answer yourself, or you've specifically written your question and answer to illustrate a particular problem and solution.

Comment: Additionally, your question is a result of misusing a well documented library. Because of that I'd argue this question doesn't really need an accepted answer; it doesn't answer anything that reading the `data.table` documentation wouldn't address.